# Any approach to send post request for checking and inserting values in MongoDB in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to search whether student record is in cloud database or not. To do so, I want to submit student ID in the form and post to pre-build cloud MongoDB, if student ID is not found, then I am gonna add this not found ID to DB. So far, I finished the component for submitting student ID as a post request to MongoDB. It's unknown for me how to add new value to the cloud database. how can I do that in reactjs? any idea? how can I make this happen?

**what I did**:

here is the simple check student ID component where I can submit student ID as post request to given REST API, then do search value in DB and update DB accordingly.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react'

export default class CehckInStdID extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {       
        stdID: '',
        checkInStatus:'False',
        Rsvp_status: 'False'
      };
      this.onSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }
    handleSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var self = this;
      // On submit of the form, send a POST request with the data to the server.
      fetch('/getStudentList', { 
          method: 'POST',
          data: {
            stdID: self.refs.stdID
          }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.json()
        }).then(function(body) {
          console.log(body);
        });
    }
    // handle change when values is changed
    handlechange = ({target: {value}}) => this.setState(state => value.length <= 9 && !isNaN(Number(value)) && {value} || state)
    render() {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          {/* <input type="text" placeholder="enter student ID" ref="stdID" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handlechange}/> */}
          <input placeholder="enter student ID" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handlechange}/>
          <input type="submit" />
        </form>
      );
    }
  }
```

**update: what is in DB**:

here is template student record in DB:

```
[{"uin":"12323444","studentInfo":{"firstName":"alex","middleName":"","lastName":"stark","rsvpStatus":"false","checkin":"true"}},
{"uin":"670168300","studentInfo":{"firstName":"Jonathan","middleName":"Samson","lastName":"Rowe","rsvpStatus":"true","checkin":"true"}},
{"uin":"54556666","studentInfo":{"firstName":"adren","middleName":"hade","lastName":"nickson","rsvpStatus":"false","checkin":"false"}},
{"uin":"45456666","studentInfo":{"firstName":"jack","middleName":"","lastName":"woods","rsvpStatus":"Yes"}}]
```

**objective**:

I am going to check entered student ID in DB, where I can call REST API to communicate with MongoDB; if student ID is not found in DB, then I am going to add three fields: `studentID=xxxxxxxxx`, `checkInStatus=True`, `Rsvp_status=False`;

I am not sure how to do it in react. any idea to get this done? thanks

Comment: You are sending the data back to the server via fetch. Now you need logic in server to receive the data, query database then take appropriate action.

Comment: what language are you using at backend (REST api)?

Comment: Is "getStudentList" is the name of list which contains all students details? or something else

Comment: @Sisir I used javascript, I built up MongDB cloud and REST API for client, now I am working in front end, to insert, check value in DB by sending request. do you have concrete solution on this question? I am newbie to webdev, so I maybe mistaken when I stating my question, but main message is clear I think.

Comment: @PradhumnSharma yeah, `getStudentList` is API route that take me to DB.

Comment: @Sisir how can I make react component to does this job in client side? any workaround? thank you

Comment: You may need to clearify your questions. What I am getting is that you are looking for solution to add values to the database. Which is a backend concern (REST API), the reactJS component is on frontend.

Comment: @Sisir let's stick with one task, seach student ID in db, if not found student ID, send another request to add this student ID, add checkInStatus, add Rsvp status. how can I do that? any solution?

Comment: @PradhumnSharma I want to accept your answer but I found a syntax error, could you correct your solution?

Comment: Ok I have resolved the error. The closing bracket was missing. Now it is fine. So please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
  // On submit of the form, instead of sending a POST request with the data to the server, first of all get all the data of students list from server and then compare the id of each student in the collection with the student id received in the form. Like this

```
handleSubmit(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var self = this;
      fetch('/getAllStudentsList').then(function(response) {
      let responseData = response.json();
      for (let eachData in responseData){
          if(responseData[eachData].uin == self.refs.stdID){
              console.log("Data is already present");
              return;
          }
          else{
              this.setState({
                 studentID:xxxxxxxxx, 
                 checkInStatus:True, 
                 Rsvp_status:False
              }, ()=>{
                     fetch("/addNewStudent",{
                         method:'POST',                             
                         body: {this.state.studentID,
                                           this.state.checkInStatus,
                                           this.state.studentID} 
                     }).then(function(response) {
                           return response.json()
                     }).then(function(body) {
                           console.log(body);
                     })
              })
          }
      }
  })
}
```

I wish it will help you and give you main idea behind the approach.

Comment: This will work you only need to change the exact api names but the structure will be same. If you want I can explain the entire structure

Comment: Could your provide full JSfiddle solution to see how your code works with dummy DB and data? I want to see how's your output looks like. thank you

Comment: does it possible to have [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) solution or [demo app](https://stackblitz.com/), it would be super helpful to understand your output. Plus, is that possible to make your solution more dynamic, I mean when we are going to send request to add new entries to DB, in your solution, else{this.setState({studentID:xxxxxxxxx, checkInStatus:True, Rsvp_status:False} is not very efficient. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have added that part also where you send data to store in database. Please check there is a callback function in this.setState method.